# Phpmailer how allowed user to upload only pdf or docs in PHP

Tags: php, phpmailer

How can i restrict users to upload only PDF or DOCS format through contact form.

I tried but unable to get over this problem. Any help over this will help me a lot.

Here is my code.

```
<?php
require('phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php');

$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->SMTPDebug = 0;
$mail->SMTPAuth = TRUE;
$mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";
$mail->Port     = 587;  
$mail->Username = "";
$mail->Password = "";
$mail->Host     = "smtp.gmail.com";
$mail->Mailer   = "smtp";
$mail->From = $_POST["userEmail"];
$mail->FromName = $_POST['userName'];
//$mail->SetFrom($_POST["userEmail"]);
$mail->AddReplyTo($_POST["userEmail"], $_POST["userName"]);
$mail->AddAddress("");  
$mail->Subject = "Career request by " . $_POST['userName'];
$mail->WordWrap   = 80;
// /$mail->MsgHTML($_POST["userName"]."\r\n"$_POST["userEmail"]);
$mail->MsgHTML("Applicant Name: ".$_POST['userName']."<br/><br/>Applicant Email: ".$_POST['userEmail']." <br/><br/>Applicant Mobile Number: ".$_POST['userPhone']."<br/><br/> Job Applied For : ".$_POST['jobApplied']);
if(is_array($_FILES)) {
$mail->AddAttachment($_FILES['attachmentFile']['tmp_name'],$_FILES['attachmentFile']['name']); 
}

$mail->IsHTML(true);

if(!$mail->Send()) {
    echo "<p class='error'>Problem in Sending Mail.</p>";
} else {
    echo "<p class='success'>Contact Mail Sent.</p>";
}   
?>
```

Thank you..

Comment: You have to check your file type first and then if the check pass then send your email

Comment: @AmrAly can you please help me to do that. i am very new to php. can you please change the possible codes here . Thanks

Comment: you can explode the file name with dot, pick the last index and if its not doc, docx or pdf.. return a message.

Comment: @Faiz99 i am unable to get it. sorry  new to php.

Comment: You have based your code on an obsolete example that will not work with recent versions of PHPMailer, which also suggests you're using an old, buggy, and vulnerable version, so I suggest you [update immediately](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer). Your code also fails to handle uploads safely, unlike the examples provided with PHPMailer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check your uploaded file using so many ways for example:

```
$file = explode('.', strtolower($_FILES['attachmentFile']['name']));
$extension = end($file);
$allowed_types = ["pdf", "docs"];

if (!in_array($extension, $allowed_types)) {
   echo "Allowed types are pdf and docs.";
} else {
   // send your email
}
```

Comment: where should i put this ?

Comment: At the top of your file after requiring your phpMailer class so if the check passes you can then send the email and don't forget to put the rest of your code into the **esle** block

Comment: please please do the changes in my code... I am getting errors again and again.

Comment: To check if that works comment all your code except your check and see if file validation is working or not

Comment: You're still stuck??

Comment: in which part ?

Comment: i am unable to debug this code with my code.. in validation part. is it possible for you to change my code with yours ?

Comment: to enable the debug mode add `error_reporting(E_ALL);` after the opening php tags and tell me what errors do you get

Comment: Thank you @AmrAly for your time. but sadly my bad that i am unabl eto fix this one.

Comment: it's o-k i just want to help but at least to solve your problem you need to know what errors  you get

Comment: can you able to edit my code with what you ask me to do. i know this is silly but i am clueless what to do .

Comment: I just need you to tell me what error you get to be able to help you

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' on line 8

Comment: Be aware that this code is potentially unsafe; you are trusting user-supplied input without checking it. Follow the directions given in [PHP's docs on handling uploads](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php), and base your code on [the send file upload example](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/send_file_upload.phps) provided with PHPMailer. Note that you can also provide some client-side filtering to only allow the file selector to pick certain file types; look up the docs on the HTML `file` tag.

Comment: @Synchro I totally agree with you but since the user is absolute beginner to PHP and probably doesn't know too much about security concerns So I thought it is not important in such phase and i was trying to make it work. **BTW** I am a big fan of you and really appreciate what you are doing for the `php` community.

Comment: Thanks. It's all the more important to point out security problems to beginners - it's still code that's likely to go into production - to raise awareness that such things exist. It's also a good idea to encourage novices to read docs, especially when the PHP docs are so good! To be fair, this precise code does not present any real threat - but there is an underlying suggestion to trust what is in `$_FILES` that should be mentioned as a risk, which is why I commented.

Comment: @Synchro That make prefect sense to me